# How to implement appSettings in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, f#, app-config

I'm trying to get rid of a warning I get using `appSettings` in a WPF project.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  ...

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Language" value="English" />
    <add key="Department" value="Production" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Model**

```
open System.Configuration

type UserSettings = {
    Language    : string
    Department  : string
} with 
    static member Null =
        {
        Language    = "English"
        Department  = "Production"
        }
    static member Load() =
        let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        {
        Language    = config.AppSettings.Settings.["Language"].Value
        Department  = config.AppSettings.Settings.["Department"].Value
        }
    member this.Save() =
        let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        config.AppSettings.Settings.["Language"].Value   <- this.Language
        config.AppSettings.Settings.["Department"].Value <- this.Department
        config.Save()
```

**ViewModel**

```
open FSharp.ViewModule

type SettingsViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()    

    let settings    = UserSettings.Load()

    let department  = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Department @>, settings.Department)

    ...
```

**View**

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=mySolution"
    xmlns:fsxaml="http://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml"
    Title="{Binding Department}" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SettingsViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    ...

</Window>
```

The visual designer marks the line `<local:SettingsViewModel/>` and gives a warning:

> Object reference not set to an instance of a reference.

This seems to be caused by the order in which the individual layers (MVVM) are initiated.

Changing

```
let settings    = UserSettings.Load()
```

to

```
let settings    = UserSettings.Null
```

resolves the warning.

*Second approach*

```
open FSharp.Configuration
type configSettings = AppSettings<"app.config">
```

This time the line `<local:SettingsViewModel/>` gives an error (still builds):

> Error 1 Cannot find name Language in 'appSettings' section of config
>   file. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\XDesProc.exe.Config)

Is there a way to implement `appSettings` that doesn't lead to warnings/errors?

**EDIT**

Layers used for the second approach:

**Model**

```
open FSharp.Configuration
type UserSettings = AppSettings<"app.config">
```

**ViewModel**

```
open FSharp.ViewModule

type SettingsViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()    

    let department  = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Department @>, UserSettings.Department)

    ...
```

Comment: How you use the second approach? I can not reproduce the error.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thanks for having a look, updated my question.

Comment: You're doing stuff in the constructor that doesn't behave properly at design time.  Solution: don't do that.  How? Lots of ways.  IsInDesignMode, adding a catch, moving on because it doesn't really matter, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Will, IsInDesignMode does the trick.