# MVVM - ConfigurationManager creates "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, view

I have this issue, it is not blocking but I want to remove it.

In my ***MainWindow.xaml*** I have this line underlined:

```
<views:XXXView Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" x:Name = "XXXViewControl"  />
```

The underline message says "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object** "

I backtracked my error and I found in ***XXXViewControl.cs*** this line:

```
public String CONNEXION_BD_GEOPOL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXXX"].ConnectionString;
```

**If this line is removed, the underlined message disappears**.

Also, in my App.Config there is the ConnectionString line, I can retrieve it nicely:

```
  <connectionStrings>
         <add name="XXXXX" connectionString="xxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I need help to solve this issue without having to remove the ConfigurationManager line.

(*This stack user solved this problem, but he's using VBA and I didn't understand what he meant :
[How to implement appSettings in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464203/how-to-implement-appsettings-in-mvvm)*)

Thanks.

Comment: Does your _App.config_ file contain a connection string whose key is **XXXXX**?

Comment: Indeed, the string is retrieved nicely. I just want to remove the warning message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object " in ***Mainwindow.xaml***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add these lines:

```
#if DEBUG
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) return;
#endif
```

This will stop execution and your designer will work fine and also it won't have an affect when application is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App.config` has to contain the connection string you are requesting through `ConfigurationManager`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="..."
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now you can get your connection string in code:

```
public String CONNEXION_BD_GEOPOL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString;
```